# Countable sets: Show there exists a bijection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that a nonempty set $T_1$ is finite if and only if there exists a bijection from $T_1$ onto a finite set $T_2$.

Edit of the foward direction
Proof: ($\rightarrow$)- Assume that $T_1$ is a nonempty finite set where $T_1=\{a_1,...,a_n|  n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. By definition there exists a bijection from the set of natural numbers to $T_1$. Let $f:T_1\rightarrow\mathbb{N}_m$ where $f(a_m)=m$ where $1\leq m \leq n$. If we let $\mathbb{N_m}=T_2$, we see that  $T_2$ is clearly finite since there is one to one correspondence. Thus existence is proven

Edit of the foward direction 
$(\leftarrow)$ Assume there exists a bijection from $T_1\rightarrow T_2$ where $T_2$ is a finite set and since $T_2$ is finite there exists a bijective function $g:T_2\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_m$ where $\mathbb{N_m}=\{1,...,m| m\in\mathbb{N}\}$ Since $f$ and $g$ are bijective functions then $f o  g$ exists and it is bijective function from $T_1\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_m$. Thus $T_1$ is finite since $\mathbb{N}_m$ is finite..

Would this be right?

Comment: If there exists an injection $S \to \mathbb N$, $S$ is not necessarily countable. The empty set satisfies this property. You probably mean an injection $\mathbb N \to S$ ; that would make more sense. Similarly, if there exists a surjection $\mathbb N \to S$, $S$ is not necessarily countable ; $S = \{1\}$ satisfies this property. A surjection $S \to \mathbb N$ would give you the property that $S$ is infinite, although we don't know if it would be countable.

Comment: you mean the theorem?

Comment: I mean the theorem you're trying to prove, as stated, is false. Just take $S = \{1\}$ ; there exists an injection from $\{1\}$ to $\mathbb N$ ; just map $1$ to $1$, the map is clearly injective, but $\{1\}$ is not countable. Similarly, you can map $\mathbb N \to \{1\}$ by sending everything to $1$ and the map will be surjective, but $\{1\}$ is again not countable.

Comment: Not sure but my book says to prove it. But they say $T_1$ is nonempty and finite.

Comment: I'm talking about your theorem 1.3.10. The three statements $A$,$B$ and $C$ are not equivalent the way you wrote them.

Comment: By countable do you mean "finite or $|\mathbb N|$"? I think that's where I understood everything wrong. I usually think of countable as infinite..

Comment: Finite. My book states a set is countable if it is either finite or denumerable.

Comment: Ahhhh. Okay sorry about my comments. Your theorem is fine. Let me read the proof now

Comment: Question : How do you define "finite"? That's actually important here because there are many ways to say it.

Comment: A set that is finite if its either empty or has n elements where $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: $T_2$ can be empty but that case be trivial. So I assumed $T_2$ is finite and nonempty which I think I should have said.

Comment: "By definition there exists a bijection from the set of natural numbers to $T_1$ or vice versa" is wrong. That would be the case if we were applying the definition of "$T_1$ is denumerable".  But instead we are assuming $T_1$ is finite.  And in any case the "vice versa" is redundant because any bijection has an inverse that is also a bijection.

Comment: You have a similar problem in the reverse direction.  $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite.  Any set that is in bijective correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, not finite!

Comment: I fixed it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  I noticed that your book is not using the usual set-theoretic definition of natural numbers, where $n = \{0,1,2,\ldots, n-1\}$.  Namely, $0$ is not considered to be a natural number, so the prototypical $n$-element set is the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ rather than $n$ itself.  I will update my answer to reflect this.

I think you are making this more complicated that it needs to be.  The notion of countability does not seem to be relevant.  As you said, we define a set $x$ to be *finite* if there is a bijection between $x$ and some natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (or it is empty.)  Let $x$ be a nonempty set.

If $x$ is finite, then there is a bijection from $x$ onto a finite set $y$: namely, let $y=x$ and consider the identity function.

Conversely, assume there is a bijection $f$ from $x$ onto a finite set $y$. By definition of "finite" there is a bijection $g$ from $y$ onto the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ for some natural number $n$. You can then show that the composition $g \circ f$ is a bijection from $x$ onto the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, so $x$ is finite as well.

---

One problem with your argument for the forward direction is that the theorem you are applying deals with countable sets rather than finite sets, so you cannot use it to conclude that there is a bijection from anything to a finite set.  In fact, the theorem is irrelevant.  I didn't finish reading the rest of this direction.

Your argument for the reverse direction is vague.  You are proving that something is finite, so you should mention some natural number $n$, some set of the form $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and some bijection between this set and some other set.

Comment: So my proof works but I need to clean it up then?

Comment: yeah in our book we don't consider 0 to be a natural number.

Comment: @user60887 As far as I understand your proof, I don't think it is correct.  I will edit my answer to explain why.

Comment: @user60887 I think you need to worry about more than correctness. The statement is very easy, as Trevor's proof indicates. Your proof, even if correct, is a rather confusing way of going about it, and indicates you do not understand these concepts as well as it would be desirable. You can always go to the corner grocery by taking a plane to the Patagonia, and hitchhiking back; it does not mean it makes sense to proceed that way.

Comment: But a countable set is defined as being finite or denumerable.

Comment: @user60887 Yes, so how are you concluding that the set $S$ you say is given by the theorem has the form $\{1,\ldots,m\}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$? It could be infinite (namely, it could be denumerable.)  Anyway, do you see why the notion of denumerable set is irrelevant to what you are trying to prove?

Comment: oh i gave a pictures of the pages in my book maybe that should help you. I think there is a lot of confusion about the definitions.

Comment: @user60887 Sorry, but I don't feel like taking the time to read through all of that.  I think your next step should either be to address my objections to your proof, or else to abandon your proof for the moment in order to review the basic concepts it deals with.

Comment: @user60887 The moral of the story is that you don't need to read any of that stuff after definition 1.3.1 in order to prove this proposition.